# Primes of the form $x^2+5xy+5y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Trying to describe all primes of the form:

$$x^2+5xy+5y^2$$

A hint was given with the question to show all primes $p$ for which 5 is a quadratic residue mod $p$. I've been able to show that all primes $\pm1$ mod 5 satisfy this... but I don't know how this helps. Any next-step pointers would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm curious. What book is this from? What examples have they done so far where they prove the primes are represented? This particular example is the easiest indefinite form with odd middle coefficient.

Comment: I don't think it's from a book. It was given as a homework question. The book I'm reading for the course is "A Concise INtroduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Alan Baker

Comment: I lied. I just checked the book. It's actually in there as Question 2 on page 41

Comment: I think the book is meant to be a collection of notes. It doesn't have any examples, since that would be nice!

Comment: Take a look at my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236087/numbers-representable-as-x2-2y2/236147#236147 which is for a positive form of discriminant $-8.$ Your form is indefinite, discriminant $5,$ and represents the same primes  as $u^2 - 5 v^2.$ Both class number one.

Comment: Have a look at my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232631/primes-for-1-good-expression/233187#233187

Comment: @Gerry, I see what you mean. The OP for that question seems to answer them under a different name and accept those. The common act is the extra ! characters while typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um, look, any (positive) odd prime with $(5|p) = (p | 5) = 1$ can be used to produce a binary quadratic form $f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2,$ or $\langle a,b,c \rangle,$ with particular coefficients $\langle p,\beta,\gamma \rangle$ with discriminant $\Delta = \beta^2 - 4 p \gamma = 5.$ This can then be reduced to $\langle 1,1,-1 \rangle$ or the equivalent  $\langle -1,1,1 \rangle,$ showing that we can write $p = u^2 + u v - v^2.$ A small change shows $p = x^2 + 5 x y + 5 y^2,$ maybe you can do that part.

See [Numbers representable as $x^2 + 2y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236087/numbers-representable-as-x2-2y2/236147#236147)

Note that reduction for indefinite forms is a little different from positive. We can arrange $\langle a,b,c \rangle,$ such that $0 < b < \sqrt \Delta$ and
$ \sqrt \Delta - b < 2 |a| < \sqrt \Delta + b$ and there are more than one,  a finite number of reduced forms in each equivalence class.

Reduction can be arranged by a finite sequence of these steps:  take the "Hessian" matrix of the  form $\langle a,b,c \rangle,$ as
$$
H = \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  2a  &  b  \\
  b  &  2c  
\end{array} 
  \right).
$$ 
Now take the matrix $P \in SL_2 \mathbb Z$ given by
$$
P = \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  0  &  -1  \\
  1  &  \delta  
\end{array} 
  \right)
$$
and calculate
$$ G = P^T H P.    $$
Now, $G$ is the Hessian matrix of an "equivalent" form (think about how to go back from a Hessian matrix to a form). A correct choice of the integer $\delta$ takes the form closer to reduced, after a few such steps the form is reduced, and further steps take the form through a cycle of equivalent forms, back to the first reduced one. The absolute values of the $\delta$'s (once reduced) are the digits for the repeated part of the continued fraction for a certain quadratic irrational, tied up with Pell's equation.  The continued fraction with all "digits" equal to $1$ is the Golden Ratio. I'm just sayin'.

================

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle
Input three coefficients a b c for indef f(x,y)= a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 
   1       5      5  

  0  form              1           5           5  delta      0
  1  form              5          -5           1  delta     -2
  2  form              1           1          -1


          -1           2
           0          -1

To Return  
          -1          -2
           0          -1

0  form   1 1 -1   delta  -1
1  form   -1 1 1   delta  1
2  form   1 1 -1
minimum was   1rep 1 0 disc   5 dSqrt 2.2360679775  M_Ratio  5
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-1  -1
-1  -2
 Trace:  -3   gcd(a21, a22 - a11, a12) : 1
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

==================

Comment: merci *********