# Prove the binary quadratic forms $5x^2+xy+y^2$ and $x^2-xy+5y^2$ are equivalent

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to show the binary quadratic forms 
$$5x^2+xy+y^2$$ and $$x^2-xy+5y^2$$ are equivalent. We've only touched on quadric forms, and the only definition I have for "equivalence" is that one can be transformed into the other via a substitution:

$$x = px' +qy', \hspace{15mm}y=rx'+sy'$$

with $ps-qr=1$. How can I find such a substitution? Or is there a way to do this without actually having to find the substitution itself?

Thank you guys for any insight into this. This is getting beyond what I can keep in my head

Comment: Please do me a favor, given any $f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2,$ abbreviated as $\langle a,b,c \rangle, $ perform the same process as in my answer and find that equivalent form, then do the same starting over with $ \langle a,b,c \rangle $ but use the matrix on the right side given by $$
P = \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  1  &  t  \\
  0  &  1  
\end{array} 
  \right)
$$ for integer $t.$ These suffice for positive forms.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236146/primes-of-the-form-x25xy5y2/236178#236178 for a short discussion of equivalence for indefinite forms.

Comment: Great link, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Take the "Hessian" matrix of the first form as
$$
H = \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  10  &  1  \\
  1  &  2  
\end{array} 
  \right)
$$ 
Now take the matrix $P \in SL_2 \mathbb Z$ given by
$$
P = \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  0  &  -1  \\
  1  &  0  
\end{array} 
  \right)
$$
and calculate
$$  P^T H P    $$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've been looking into this, but can't seem to get it to turn out. I must be missing something. I'm naively trying $\dbinom{x'}{y'} = P^THP \dbinom{x}{y}$ and not getting desired results. Clearly I'm missing something..

Comment: Or maybe I'm incompetent in carrying out the calculation. lol.

Comment: @MargretButton, the matrix $P^T H P$ is the Hessian matrix of another, equivalent, quadratic form. That is equivalence, multiplication of the Hessian matrix on the right by a matrix of determinant 1 and on the left by its transpose.

Comment: Ohhh..That makes so much more sense lol. Much appreciated!